# Select method of Range class failed after selecting worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use autofill to populate a worksheet with the same number of rows as another worksheet. I'm getting the "AutoFill method of Range class failed" error message. It's not able to find the range that I want to start from.

I searched a few other questions like this and they suggested placing it in a module (Which was already the case for me) or activating the worksheet before trying to autofill the data. Neither worked so far

```
    'Working between 2 workbookss
    Dim Transactions As Workbook
    Set Transactions = ActiveWorkbook

    'Sells
    Dim SellData As Worksheet
    Set SellData = Transactions.Sheets("SellData")

    Dim lrSell As Long
    SellData.Activate
    lrSell = Cells(Rows.Count, "H:H").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim MonthlySales As Worksheet
    Set MonthlySales = Transactions.Sheets("Monthly Sales")
    MonthlySales.Activate
    MonthlySales.Range("A2:CG2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:CG" & (lrSell - 2))
    'Error happens on last line MonthlySales.Range("A2:CG2")
```

I also tried

```
    MonthlySales.Activate
    MonthlySales.Range("A2:CG2").Select              'This is where the error would come up
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:CG" & (lrSell - 2))
```

In the end, Sell data and Monthly sales should have the same row number. The reason for all of this is to reformat the data.

Comment: In general, you want to [avoid using Activate and select](how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) in your code. It's also a good idea to specify the worksheet for all the ranges in your code

Comment: What is the value of `lrSell`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't `Activate` sheets to make unqualified member calls work.

> ```
> SellData.Activate
> lrSell = Cells(Rows.Count, "H:H").End(xlUp).Row
> ```

Qualify the member calls instead.

```
lrSell = SellData.Cells(SellData.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
```

Same here:

> ```
> Dim MonthlySales As Worksheet
> Set MonthlySales = Transactions.Sheets("Monthly Sales")
> MonthlySales.Activate
> MonthlySales.Range("A2:CG2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A3:CG" & (lrSell - 2))
> ```

Use explicit qualifiers - `Range` (or `Cells`) used without a qualifier is almost always a bug waiting to happen.

```
Dim MonthlySales As Worksheet
Set MonthlySales = Transactions.Sheets("Monthly Sales")
MonthlySales.Range("A2:CG2").AutoFill Destination:=MonthlySales.Range("A2:CG" & (lrSell - 2))
```

Note that this will throw error 1004 if `lrSell - 2` is zero or negative. Best assert that it isn't the case:

```
lrSell = SellData.Cells(SellData.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row
Debug.Assert lrSell > 2 ' we're subtracting 2 later, so this must be 3+
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me clean up my code but I'm still receiving the same issue

```
MonthlySales.Range("A2:CG2").AutoFill Destination:=MonthlySales.Range("A3:CG" & (lrSell - 2))
```

Comment: FYI, the current value for lrSell is 1478

Comment: @signup4stuffmatt try including row 2 in your destination range

Comment: That was it... Insane how one number breaks everything.. Thank you for your help